# Django rest auth extend registration form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using Django-rest-auth for authentication and registration. I am using email to loging in the user with password. ***I want to store user's first name and last name at the time of registration*** (perhaps few more fields) i.e. On client side on registration form will have following fields(email, password, first name, last name, etc..). Currently registration form has only email, password 1 and password 2 fields and registration is basically successful.

[image]

My settings.py has following:

```
#This is required otherwise it asks for email server
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True   
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

#Following is added to enable registration with email instead of username
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
# Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
"django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

#`allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
"allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend", 
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Are you trying to extend the user model to add more fields?

Comment: I am not sure if I am actually extending user model, now I have to go in my admin interface and manually add first name , last name etc. attributes to a user. I want to have these fields in my registration form so that on successful registration this data is automatically saved for newly created user.

Comment: Ok i think I know what you want to do, look at my answer below

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extend the registration form, you're going to need to create your own custom user that has more fields.

So in your models file have this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
   AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin,
)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.TextField(default='')
    last_name = models.TextField(default='')
    #any other fields you want

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

then in your settings you want this

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.CustomUser'
```

and then django rest should use this user model as when you visit this form page

I hope this helps!

**EDIT**

I believe this should automatically handle passwords since it extends AbtractBaseUser, let me know if it doesn't

Comment: It gives me in console> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'flights.CustomUser' that has not been installed. Before migrating of course, should I migrate?

Comment: yea you need to migrate :)

Comment: did you do makemigrations before migrating?

Comment: ERROR: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146,"Table'swarms_flight.flights_customuser_user_permissions' doesn't exist")

Comment: you ran makemigrations?

Comment: Okay it worked, I now have a table flights_customuser created in my database. However on registration page I still see the same fields (username, email, pass1, pass2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109941/discussion-between-charles-haro-and-nitish).